# How to install git server with apache authentication on Ubuntu 14

Tags: server, apache2, authentication, git

I trying to install git server on Ubuntu 14 following these steps: [www.jmuras.com](http://jmuras.com/blog/2012/git-server-with-apache-authentication-on-ubuntudebian/)

I made a little change when creating `git.conf` and symbolic link cause goes on different folders for Ubuntu 14, i did it on

`/etc/apache2/conf-available/git.conf`

and symbolic link on

`/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/git.conf` to `/etc/apache2/conf-available/git.conf`

Everythings seems to work fine, but when i try to clone the project, after authenticate got this error:

```
fatal: http://testserver.com/git/newProject/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

and on apache access log:

```
192.168.70.1 - user [18/May/2014:16:24:54 -0700] "GET /git/newProject/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 404 457 "-" "git/1.8.0.msysgit.0"

404 error
```

Any suggestion?

What's wrong?

Comment: To echo your error message, did you run `git update-server-info` in your `newProject` repository on the server? It's shown in the steps you linked to.

Comment: yes, i followed all steps

Comment: There are two ways to set up git over http. The instructions you are following from the blog link are for the "dumb" protocol. I don't know why, but there seems to be some interaction with your setup that is making the dumb protocol fail. Try setting the environment variable `GIT_SMART_HTTP=1` on your client, does it work then? You might want to look at a more recent set of instructions for setting up smart http, for example from the official documentation of [git-http-backend](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-http-backend).